# VBA Test if optional variant exists

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a method:

`Public Sub Method1(Optional Append As Variant)`

And I want to check to see if the `Append` argument was passed or not, so I was trying:

```
Public Sub Method1(Optional Append As Variant)
    If Not Append Is Nothing Then ... End If
End Sub
```

But this conditional testing only works if `Append` was passed, otherwise `Append` just doesn't exist and we get an error.

Is there a way to test this without relying on `"On Error Goto"` ?

Comment: [`IsMissing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ismissing-function?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1010101)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: You need to use IsMissing.  eg. If IsMissing(Append) then

Comment: You can set a default to `Optional Append as variant=0` and test that way also.